# Visual Studio Showing Task List Items From Deleted Files

Tags: visual-studio

I used the Ctrl+K, Ctrl+H shortcut in some .xaml files to add some TODOs to the Visual Studio Task List. I've subsequently deleted those files but the TODOs from those files continue to appear in the Task List. I've cleaned the solution and rebuilt, exited Visual Studio and restarted, cleared the ComponentCache, the temp directory, the Roslyn cache, and the ProjectEvaluation folder all to no avail.

How can I get those items out of the Task List?